# Find and specific pattern and extract data from a column having string values

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

Using MSSQL Server 2012

I have a column name **LocationName** with the following data in it.

| LocationName |
| --- |
| C1-Highland |
| C687-I-10 & 51st |
| C74-Bossier |
| C0716-South Broadway & Cluff |
| Las Vegas |

I want to find only those records which is having pattern like {CXXXX} where XXXX can be any number between 0-9.

```
SELECT
     CASE 
        WHEN LocationName like 'C%' THEN SUBSTRING(LocationName, 0, charindex('-', LocationName, 
        0))
        ELSE 'Unknown'+ '-' + LocationName
    END AS storebusinesskey,* 
FROM [DBO].[Store]
```

The problem with this code is if I have location name start with C but not having pattern {CXXXX} then also I'm getting this record ,which I didn't want.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `[]` to use regex that matches what you want

You said that XXXX can be any number between 0-9

If you want the first 4 digit is number 0-9, then you need to repeat `[]` 4 times

```
SELECT * FROM [DBO].[Store]
WHERE LocationName like '[C]'+ REPLICATE('[0-9]', 4) + '%'
```

If you just want first digit is number 0-9, then you can simply to the following:

```
SELECT * FROM [DBO].[Store]
WHERE LocationName like '[C][0-9]%'
```

Comment: `LIKE` is not regex

Answer (score 0):

If you want four or more digits, you can use:

```
SELECT (CASE WHEN LocationName like 'C[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]%'
             THEN SUBSTRING(LocationName, 1, charindex('-', LocationName, 0))
             ELSE 'Unknown'+ '-' + LocationName
        END) AS storebusinesskey,* 
FROM [DBO].[Store];
```

Note:  This logic is a little strange because the `WHEN` condition is not guaranteeing that there is a hyphen.

If you want exactly four digits -- and no more -- then you need to tweak the logic a bit:

```
SELECT (CASE WHEN LocationName + 'x' like 'C[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][^0-9]%'
             THEN SUBSTRING(LocationName, 1, charindex('-', LocationName, 0))
             ELSE 'Unknown'+ '-' + LocationName
        END) AS storebusinesskey,* 
FROM [DBO].[Store];
```

This checks that the following character is not a digit.  The `+ 'x'` simply ensures that the check works if the C#### value is at the end of the string.